# Django Rest Framework foreign key multiple data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model call Schedule, it is like reminder function. I also have another model called Family which user can add family member in it.

So in schedule, i create a foreign key to link family inside so that it will include the family member id in it.

Here is the how my API for schedule looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmGSy.jpg

And here are my questions.

1. As you can see based on the image in above link, the userId is a drop down. is it possible to make it userId = self.request.user.userId ?
2. In the schedule api, the familyId is a drop down that consist of all family member(basically, even other people who added their family), is there a way to filter it so that it will only shows a dropdown of only the current user familyId appear ?
3. When creating a schedule, user can only insert 1 familyId. Is there a way to choose more than 1 familyId ? For eg, user can insert familyId 1 and 2

Here is my code

**models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Family(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)


class Schedule2(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    familyId = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'relationship')


class Schedule2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    time = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats)

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule2
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'familyId', 'title', 'desc', 'date', 'time', 'location')
```

**views**

```
class FamilyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer

    # this is to allow current user to see their own family only
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Family.objects.filter(userId=user)

class ScheduleViewSet2(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Schedule2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Schedule2Serializer
```

Comment: The DRF API form is just a helper. You do not need to tweak it. Just add the needed validations in respective serializers and you are good to go (this should answer your first and second question). For third question: You can't because of your database design. Your Schedule model expects a single ForeignKey to Family model and that is the right approach. It is fine to have multiple entries for same Schedule with different Family foreignKey fields.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the first question is "yes", you can set the `user_id` in the model to the id of the person logged in (`self.request.user`). To do this you will have to overwrite the create method.